# Problem with joining three tables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have project for ads/properties in Laravel. I have has many relationship between user and property and user and category, also many to many relationship between property and category. Here are my tables.

```
users (id, first_name, last_name, user_preferences)

properties (id, user_id, location, price)

categories (id, category)

category_property (id, category_id, property_id)
```

As logged in user when I check one or multiple checkboxes in my edit profile page and submit form I insert json values in user_preferences column in users table, for example, ["house", "flat"]. And those are values from category column in categories table. I want that logged in user to display all properties that have those values that he checked in form. I am having trouble writing query in my controller that will join those tables and get those filtered properties. With current code I get all properties. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code.

CategoryController.php

```
public function index(Category $category, Property $property, User $user)
{
   preferedAdsResults = $property
    ->orderBy('page_views', 'desc')
    ->paginate(5, ['*'], 'preferedAdsResults');

    return view('startpage', compact('preferedAdsResults'));
}
```

edit.blade.php

```
<div class="row page-hero d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <label for="preferences" class="text-center">Select your preferences</label>         
    </div>
    <div class="row">                
        <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-right:15px; margin-left:60px;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input id="house" name="user_preferences[]" value="house" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" @if(is_array(old('user_preferences', $user->user_preferences)) && in_array('house', old('user_preferences', $user->user_preferences))) checked @endif>
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="house">house</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-right:15px;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input id="flat" name="user_preferences[]" value="flat" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" @if(is_array(old('user_preferences', $user->user_preferences)) && in_array('flat', old('user_preferences', $user->user_preferences))) checked @endif>
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="flat">flat</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-right:50px;">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input id="room" name="user_preferences[]" value="room" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" @if(is_array(old('user_preferences', $user->user_preferences)) && in_array('room', old('user_preferences', $user->user_preferences))) checked @endif>
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="room">room</label>
            </div>
        </div>          
</div>
```

startpage.blade.php

```
<div class="col-2">
    <h1>Prefered ads</h1>

        @if (isset($preferedAdsResults))
            @foreach ($preferedAdsResults as $preferedAdsResult)
                <div class="row">
                    <a href="{{route('property.show',['id'=>$preferedAdsResult->id])}}">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" disabled style="margin-top:10px;">{{$preferedAdsResult->price}} eur</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" disabled style="margin-top:10px;">{{$preferedAdsResult->location}}/button>
                        <hr>
                    </a>
                </div>
            @endforeach
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col"></div>
                    <div class="col">{{ $preferedAdsResults->links() }}</div>
                    <div class="col"></div>
                </div>
        @endif
</div>
```

Category.php

```
public function property()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Property::class);
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Property.php

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

User.php

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
}

public function property()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Property', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: You're missing **$** in `preferedAdsResults = $property` right after declaring `index(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [Query Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#query-scopes) to the Property model and then, when preferences for the user in question exist, call the scope.  Your logic for filtering by the preferences will be located in the scope.

```
        Property::with(['category', 'user'])
        ->when(isset($user->user_preferences), function($q) use ($user) {
            $q->preferences($user->user_preferences);
        })
        ->orderBy('page_views', 'desc')
        ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong, with this I still get all properties, and not those filtered

Comment: Your property needs to have types (e.g. House / Flat etc.).  I don't see this in your tables that you described above, however, assuming it does and your user preferences are correct it will work.

Comment: flat/house are values in users table under user_preferences column

Comment: yes, I can see that, but they need to correspond to a property type or else you are returning both flats and houses.

Comment: Well, if house and flat are stored in user_preferences column like this ["house", "flat"] I want to display all properties that have those two values. I'm confused, where should I add property type and what for?